# how to show all nintex tasks (any type) in one single page or form (method is not matter)

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

i'm working in a SharePoint consultant company and one of our customers wants their employees can see all tasks in a single page.
i know there is a web part for get list of all Nintex tasks. but they don't want seeing just link of tasks and click on them and task form get opened. they want a page of all opened task forms.
is a there any way to doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot open many tasks forms from a single page. Since you already know about the web part, we don't need talk about it.

You can create a new form which contain all the variable (data) needed for every task you want to update and see, then distribute the data to the other list using **Nintex Workflow**, you can add web part from the other list at that new form list, so you can update data and see it in one page.